# Como adicionar somente as DLLs necessarias para um aplicativo (--self-contained)?

Tags: .net-core

Para gerar/publicar um aplicativo em [net-core](/questions/tagged/net-core) use o comando:

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained
```

Se tiver configurado o `.csproj` com `<RuntimeIdentifier>`, ou então uso este (exemplo se for publicar para windows 10 64bit):

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r windows10-x64
```

No entanto ao publicar notei que são enviados todas dlls, muitas que nem uso em meu projeto, exemplo:

> [image: dlls publicadas]

Realmente a aplicação só usa algumas coisas e a única lib que adicionei via nuget tenho certeza que não usa tantas coisas assim, isto realmente é normal na hora de publicar com `--self-contained`, ou é possivel limitar somente ao necessário?

Comment: Se você publicar uma aplicação com a opção [--self-contained](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore30) será publicado junto do aplicativo o run-time completo do [tag:net-core]. Para limitar ao necessário a [implantação auto-contida](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd) deve ser preterida em favor de uma [opção implantação dependente de estrutura](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/deploying/index#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd)...

Comment: ... e por isso um comentário e não uma resposta, pois uma resposta estaria fora do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques para falar a verdade, eu já sei a resposta, mas deixo para outras pessoas tentarem resolver, tem sim forma de amenizar, indo somente o que é necessário, claro incluindo o net-core-runtime, que é muita coisa, mas economiza uns 20mb em média em um aplicativo simples.

Comment: Mas como assim economizando memória com runtime-time completo. Você está falando do netcore warp?Se for eu não sei utilizá-lo, mas sei que diminui sensivelmente o resultado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não, tem dll q realmente não é necessaria, é só isso, economiza 20mb de espaço, ou de  dlls, mas dependendo do que vc importou ou adicionou no nuget isso nem tem efeito, é que eu tava esperando uma resposta razoavel, mas vou eu mesmo responder, só estou terminando outras coisas open-source aqui :)

Answer (score 0):

É completamente normal e veja o porque segundo a documentação da Microsoft:

> Implantação autocontida. Ao contrário da FDD, a SCD (implantação
>   autocontida) não se baseia na presença de componentes compartilhados
>   no sistema de destino. Todos os componentes, inclusive as bibliotecas
>   e o runtime do .NET Core, são incluídos com o aplicativo e isolados de
>   outros aplicativos .NET Core. As SCDs incluem um arquivo executável
>   (como o app.exe em plataformas Windows para um aplicativo chamado
>   app), que é uma versão renomeada do host específico da plataforma .NET
>   Core, e um arquivo .dll (como app.dll), que é o aplicativo real.